# ST_SnapToGrid makes result invalid depending on size

Tags: postgis, polygon, invalid-data

For fewer than 100 polygons in my set of ~1 million, I am getting a behaviour with [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) that I do not understand.  Depending on the parameter that I pass for `size`, the validity of the resulting geometry varies.  Is there something particular to the polygon?  What is going on here?

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.6 and PostGIS 2.5

Here are examples that use the same input polygon and differ only by the size parameter to `ST_SnapToGrid`.

`size` is **.1** and result of `st_isvalid` is **true**:

```
select st_isvalid(st_snaptogrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON (((
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
    473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
    473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574)))'), .1))
```

`size` is **.01** and result of `st_isvalid` is **false**:

```
select st_isvalid(st_snaptogrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON (((
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
    473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
    473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574)))'), .01))
```

`size` is **.001** and result of `st_isvalid` is **true**:

```
select st_isvalid(st_snaptogrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON (((
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
    473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
    473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574)))'), .001))
```

Comment: I examined more closely the resulting polygons after calling st_snaptogrid with differing size parameters and noticed that they have different numbers of vertices.  I assumed that st_snaptogrid simply rounded off each coordinate, but it instead appears to consolidate vertices if appropriate.  Which makes sense, and could explain how I'm seeing the results that I am.  I would still be happy if anyone has more insight...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ST_SnapToGrid` does

> *Remove consecutive points falling on the same cell [...]* - [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html)

but it does not perform **any further topology checks**.

You are right to assume that, apart from the above, it only rounds to any given precision value. And this is also the issue; consider a (comic-like) bone shaped polygon where two (opposite) of the vertices in the middle get rounded to the same cell: those vertices are **not consecutive**, so they won't get filtered out, but **they self-intersect**, rendering the polygon invalid!

This seems to be the case with your example:

```
SELECT ST_IsValidReason(
         ST_SnapToGrid(
          'MULTIPOLYGON (((
             473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
             473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
             473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
             473473.3724999996 5007378.8574
           )))'::GEOMETRY
         ),
         0.01
       )
;
```

returns

```
Self-intersection[473487.04 5007296.65]
```

Comment: thank you - this makes good sense

Answer (score 3):

Having a look at the geometries that SnapToGrid is returning reveals what happens.

[image: result of SnapToGrid]

As user @geozelop explained, at the lower right corner with tolerance of 0.01 two not consecutive vertices are snapped to same coordinates and because of that the polygon has a spike that makes it invalid.

You can correct the geometry with ST_MakeValid

```
select st_makevalid(
st_snaptogrid(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON (((
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
    473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
    473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574)))'), .01))
```

The corrected geometry is a geometry collection that has the spike as a separate linestring element.

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (
    POLYGON ((
            473473.37 5007378.86, 
            473487.03 5007296.71, 
            473487.04000000004 5007296.66, 
            473477.86 5007296.63, 
            473473.37 5007378.86
        )), 
    LINESTRING (
        473487.04000000004 5007296.66, 
        473487.04000000004 5007296.65
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you - the image is very helpful.  Out of curiosity, what software do you use in conjunction with Postgis to visualize geometries such as the polygons in your image?  I use QGIS in general, but it is a little clunky just to view a one-off polygon from the database.

Comment: I use OpenJUMP http://openjump.org/ and the Run Datastore Query tool. That tool creates layers directly from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS now has the [`ST_ReducePrecision`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.4/ST_ReducePrecision.html) function, which returns **valid** precision-reduced results for polygonal geometry.

```
select ST_IsValid( ST_ReducePrecision('MULTIPOLYGON (((
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574, 473487.03199999966 5007296.7063,
    473487.04140000045 5007296.6579, 473487.0406999998 5007296.6544,
    473487.03639999963 5007296.6579, 473477.86390000023 5007296.6269000005,
    473473.3724999996 5007378.8574)))', .1));

 st_isvalid 
------------
 t
```